# Deque data structure: Applications

Tags: data-structures, queue

When we can insert and delete from both ends, why is it called a deque? Also, what are the applications of a deque?

I'm a student studying data structures for the first time. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's also known as the double-ended queue.  It's called this because it provides a generalized queue which we can modify from both the head or the tail.  Hence, double-ended.

**When should we use one?**
Whenever we want fast access to inserts and deletes at both the beginning and the end.  Scheduling and modeling real life queues are common examples.

Answer (score 0):

One application I could think of is maintaining a Playlist of songs.

- Next song is played from the front of the queue(i.e. playlist).
- You can add a song to the queue (`append`) or the "play next" option adds the song to the front of the queue (`appendleft`)

For real-world application read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15038243/7477462)